# Add new item to a list created with the ko.mapping plugin for Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to figure out the canonical way to add elements to a list in a model created with ko.mapping. I [created a jsFiddle to tinker](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Rgj6u/1/):

The javascript is something along the lines of the following:

```
var mapping, baseModel, view_model;

mapping = {
    outer: [{
        alpha: '',
        beta: [
            {
            carotine: '',
            blockers: ''}
        ]
    }]
};

baseModel = { // add in functionality
    append_outer: function() {
        this.outer.push({});
    },
    append_beta: function(xyz) {
        this.beta.push({});
    }
};

view_model = ko.mapping.fromJS(mapping, {}, baseModel);

ko.applyBindings(view_model, $("#mapped")[0]);​
```

The corresponding HTML is [on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Rgj6u/1/).

When I use `append_outer` I would expect to have a new element added to the view_model essentially identical to the first element, all with observables. When I use `append_beta` I would expect beta to have a new element with `[carotine: ko.observable(), blockers: ko.observable]`. I have not seen an obvious way to do this - but I would expect it to be a very common use-case.

For obvious reasons the sample code is not doing what I desire! It is of course just what I was tinkering in the hopes of finding something obvious, e.g. `ko.mappingCreate` or some such. Alas, no such luck.

It is perhaps mentioning that the data model is dynamic - though lists will always have items with data representations identical to that of their peers. One might say that the data used to create the view model (`mapping`) is a prototype.

I would be grateful for any thoughts and direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'd do it this way... but make a object for the types that takes aspects of the mapping as a template.

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/EEE6J/

In general, I'd just define the structure with the objects and just use the json for data.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Although this is certainly an option, I would have to create an object for each type based on the same data passed to `ko.mapping.fromJS` (since it is, as mentioned, dynamically created). It seems this would be duplicating functionality that I would otherwise have expected to be inherent to `ko.mapping`, and I would prefer not to have such duplication -- though it may be necessary.

Comment: what are you duplicating?  the mapping plugin is just going through and turning things into observables.   No where is it trying to work out "types" of things are in what its mapping.  it has no idea what break down of the structure you are giving it are significant to you.  You can send a "template" structure, which is what I do with a MVC back end, which can be then used to create new items.

Comment: and while it seems like duplication, its just data of the form of its schema, looks very similar to the schema,  in your case, you are giving data with no definition of the schema,  now you are wanting a schema, it's just looking like the data :)

Comment: hmm, are you wanting that "mapping" object to be the definition of the schema?   because the way you are using it, its acting as data :)

Comment: Yes, exactly - I am using the mapping of empty data as the schema (though it could in practice contain data - being any preset defaults). Sorry if that wasn't clear. :)

Comment: its a wee bit tricky, but here I've still made the objects, but the fields come from the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Working off Keith's suggestion, I did the following:

```
var mapping, baseModel, view_model;

mapping = {
    outer: [{
        alpha: '',
        beta: [
            {
            carotine: '',
            blockers: '',
            skittles: ''}
        ]}
    ]
};

baseModel = function(mapping) { // add in functionality
    var self = this;

    this._vm_prototype = mapping;

    console.log("Prototype: " + ko.mapping.toJSON(this._vm_prototype));

    self.append = function(target, proto_getter) {
        console.log("pg: " + proto_getter);
        var prototype = proto_getter(self._vm_prototype);

        console.log("Prototype: " + JSON.stringify(prototype));
        console.log("Target: " + ko.mapping.toJSON(target));

        this[target].push(ko.mapping.fromJS(prototype));
    };
};

view_model = ko.mapping.fromJS(mapping, {}, new baseModel(mapping));

ko.applyBindings(view_model, $("#mapped")[0]);​
```

Unfortunately this requires something of a hack on the HTML side, being e.g. to add a new `beta` one has to identify where in the prototype it exists, i.e.

```
<button data-bind='click: $root.append.bind($data, "beta", 
        function (proto) { return proto.outer[0].beta[0]; })'>
  Add another beta
</button>
```

and for an `outer`

```
<button data-bind='click: append.bind($data, "outer", 
        function (proto) { return proto.outer[0]; })'>
 Add another outer
</button>
```

The `append` function could be made cleaner if it were just passed `outer[0].beta[0]` in place of the function, but then one would have to parse or `eval` this.

As one can see from the jsFiddle [A](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Rgj6u/3/) and [B](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Rgj6u/5/), the only thing that changes is the `mapping`, but the functionality works as expected for both.

Again, I am trying to avoid duplication of code, but this is ugly. I would love any thoughts on how to clean this up!